# Displaying RSS feed in all browsers

Tags: safari, cross-browser, rss

I'm trying to get some kind of human readable output in all browsers for an rss feed I'm generating.

It seems that firefox has native support for this.

After some work I also managed to get a nice output using xml-stylesheet in chrome.

Safari however does'nt attempt to display the feed at all, instead just displaying

> Safari can’t open “feed://localhost:3000/feed.xml” because Safari
>   can’t display RSS feeds.

I know what I want to do is possible because the [bbc's news RSS feed](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int) does display in safari.

I've tried several things like changing the content-type header to text/xml instead of application xml, wrapping elements in CDATA like the bbc's feed, but still cannot get this to work. does anyone have any ideas?

If it helps, I'm on safari 11.0.3

Note I haven't tried it in edge/explorer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to get this to work in safari is to add the following response headers:

```
Content-Type=text/xml; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
```